# Does a sequential stream in Java 8 use the combiner parameter on calling collect?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I call collect on a sequential stream (eg. from calling Collection.stream()) then will it use the combiner parameter I pass to collect?  I presume not but I see nothing in the documentation.  If I'm correct, then it seems unfortunate to have to supply something that I know will not be used (if I know it is a sequential stream).

Comment: What happens when you pass null for the combiner? What do you deduce from this experiment?

Comment: @JBNizet It will throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Keep in mind to develop against interface specifications -- not against the implementation. The implementation might change with the next Java version, whereas the specification should remain stable.

The specification does not differentiate between sequential and parallel streams. For that reason, you should assume, that the *combiner* might be used. Actually, there are good examples showing that *combiners* for sequential streams can improve the performance. For example, the following *reduce* operation concatenates a list of strings. Executing the code without *combiner* has quadratic complexity. A smart execution with *combiner* can reduce the runtime by magnitudes.

```
List<String> tokens = ...;
String result = tokens.stream().reduce("", String::concat, String::concat);
```

Comment: It would be *very* smart if the `Stream` implementation recognizes if using the combiner can improve performance. However, the bigger risk is that the developer him/herself changes a stream to parallel at a time (s)he has forgotten about the omitted combiner…

Comment: @Holger Right, or another developer passes a stream to your code, and that stream might change to be parallel in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the same problem, and while always adhering to develop against the interface, I find it a pity that there is no "simple" version of a collector with no combiner. That would make things MUCH easier. They could have made a `Collector.Characteristics` to indicate this, or a simpler version of the `Collector` interface...

Comment: One more question: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) I found the sentence `A sequential implementation of a reduction using a collector would create a single result container using the supplier function, and invoke the accumulator function once for each input element.` Doesn't that already indicate that the combiner isn't used in this situation?

Comment: @Holger, @ nosid I did not quite understand how the combiner you mentioned in the example will improve performance in a sequential stream. As per my understanding at any point in time, there is an accumulator string and the element in the stream. We just concat them and create a new accumulator string. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GeekFactory you are overlooking the costs of “just concat them”. String concatenation implies creating a new string that is a copy of both argument strings. The longer the string, the more overhead. And the intermediate result of multiple string concatenations is a string that grows longer and longer. You may search for “Shlemiel the Painter's Algorithm” for an intuitive picture. See also https://ideone.com/0kRRnt Just to make it clear, `collect(joining())` still is even better, but I hope you see, utilizing the combiner reduces the overhead in this example.

Comment: @Holger Wow! That is a great example to demo how combiner makes sense in sequential streams. If I am not wrong `return reduce.apply(......)` is working as combiner, right? Also is there a name for this algorithm you are using?

Comment: @GeekFactory exactly, at this point, the function acts as combiner. It’s equivalent to what the Stream API does when splitting the workload for parallel streams. When it comes to a name, I’d say, it’s a variant of [Divide-and-Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm).

Comment: Could you provide, please, detailed analysis or examples showing how this improves performance?  Or links to articles/researches?