# Is there an elegant way to reduce a stream of maps to one map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, reduce

Given some maps, is there a one-line way to put all their entries into one map?

Ignoring issues of nulls, over-writing entries etc, what I would like to code is:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> reduce(Map<K, V>... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps)
        .reduce(new HashMap<K, V>(), (a, b) -> a.putAll(b));
}
```

but this gives a compile error, because `a.putAll(b)` is `void`. If it returned `this`, it would work.

To work around this, I coded:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> reduce(Map<K, V>... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps)
        .reduce(new HashMap<K, V>(), (a, b) -> {a.putAll(b); return a;});
}
```

which compiles and works, but it's an ugly lambda; coding `return a;` feels redundant.

One approach is to refactor out a utility method:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> reduce(Map<K, V> a, Map<K, V> b) {
    a.putAll(b);
    return a;
}
```

which cleans up the lambda:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> reduce(Map<K, V>... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps)
       .reduce(new HashMap<K, V>(), (a, b) -> reduce(a, b));
}
```

but now I have a, albeit reusable, somewhat useless utility method.

Is there a more elegant way to call a method on the accumulator *and* return it within a lambda?

Comment: Unfortunately this way of using of `reduce` is fundamentally broken: it may work for sequential execution, but it will break with parallel execution. That is because the reduce() method treats its first (identity) parameter as a reusable value. So it works for primitive and immutable types, but mutable values (like `new HashMap<>()`) on parallel streams will be mutated, possibly concurrently, by different threads. That won't end well. The answer is to use `collect()`, as in @Pshemo's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`reduce` works similarly to

```
U result = identity;
for (T element : this stream)
    result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
return result;
```

which means that the lambda representing `accumulator.apply` needs to `return` result (final or intermediate one).

If you want to avoid this behaviour use `collect` which works more like

```
R result = supplier.get();
for (T element : this stream)
    accumulator.accept(result, element);
return result;
```

so lambda representing `accumulator.accept` don't need to `return` any value but to modify `result` based on `element`.

Example:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> reduce(Map<K, V>... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps)
            .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll);
            //                          ^            ^
            //                          |         collect results from parallel streams
            //                       collect results in single thread
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. This has made me realise an important difference between reduce and collect: collect can be executed in parallel, reduce not (AFAICT).

Comment: Why not? You can invoke `reduce` on `pararelStream()` like on simple `stream()`. There is even [one overloaded version for it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) which last argument lets you specify how to collecting results from parallel streams.

Comment: See my comment above. You can't use `reduce` on mutable types in parallel streams, and therefore you shouldn't use it with sequential ones either. The API isn't clear on this point, and a lot of people will make this error. The way to go is with `collect`.

Comment: The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) does't explicitly say reduce can't be done in parallel, but it does say collect can. Because reduce can change types, and seems to be a sequential operation, it seems logical to me that can't be made parallel (I could be wrong of course - I'm learning it too)

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not particularly familiar with the implementation, but `reduce` should be parallelisable. It's explicitly required to be associative, so instead of `(((a * b) * c) * d` an implementation could do `(a * b) * (c * d)` (where one thread gets `a`, `b` and the other `c`, `d`).

Comment: @Tom but with reduce, order matters: a with b gives a1, then a1 with c gives a2 etc (eg building a string via concatenation of elements in a stream), which is why I don't believe it's parallelisable. If the reduction is a one-way operation (eg a hash), which it's allowed to be, then it can't be forked because each step can't proceed without the result of the previous step. But with collect, you specify how to create, combine and aggregate results, which is plainly parallelisable.

Comment: @Bohemian For an associative operator, the order of the operations within the expression is important, not in time. In my example above, if `*` represented string concatenation, it'd still work whichever way you did it. `reduce` is not suitable for normal non-commutative hash functions (though would work, say, an implementation of `Set.hashCode`). A `foldLeft` would be suitable, but for whatever reason there isn't one (yet). ( From Stuart Marks himself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308146/why-is-a-combiner-needed-for-reduce-method-that-converts-type-in-java-8/24316429#24316429 )

Comment: @Bohemian: Of course, you have to specify a side-effect free, [*associative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) function to `reduce` in order to get consistent results with parallel reduction. If you meet the criteria, there is no problem. And to your surprise: *it works* with string concatenation, as concatenation is associative, i.e. `(a+b)+c` has the same result as `a+(b+c)` if `a`, `b` and `c` are all `String`s. This implies that also `a+b+c+d` has the same result as `(a+b)+(c+d)` and therefore `(a+b)` and `(c+d)` can be evaluated concurrently.

Comment: @Bohemian: Reduction is perfectly parallelizable, so long as your reduction function is *associative*.  The difference between `reduce` and `collect` is that `reduce` works by consuming *values* and producing new *values* (think sum, max, min), whereas `collect` works by incorporating elements into a mutable result container (a list, set, map, array, etc.)

Comment: what will happen if two or more maps have duplicate keys?

Comment: @Nitin9791 Common key will hold value of last map with same key (at least in single thread stream).