# How to reduce a limited stream (e.g. an ArrayList) from right in Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I would like to convert a list to a self-implemented linked list using `reduce`. I managed to do that in a reverse order:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Reverse {
    static class Node {
        int val;
        Node next;

        Node(int v, Node n) {
            val = v;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        Node result = numbers
                .stream()
                .reduce(null,
                        (node, val) -> new Node(val, node),
                        (n1, n2) -> new Node(-1, null));

        while(result != null) {
            System.out.println(result.val);
            result = result.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I think to obtain result in the correct order, I may have to use something like foldRight or reduceRight in other languages. Does java provide anything similar, given that the stream is guaranteed to be limited?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240414/equivalent-of-scalas-foldleft-in-java-8) might be related if not duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the newest Java 16, the current Stream API doesn't provide any operations "from the right" such as "reduceRight`.

The only possible workaround is to use [`Collections#reverse(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) method to reverse the order of the items in the collection right before applying reduction.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Collections.reverse(numbers);
Node result = numbers
    .stream()
    .reduce(null,
            (node, val) -> new Node(val, node),
            (n1, n2) -> new Node(-1, null));
```

Read more here: [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide identity and use it as starting point:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        Node result = new Node();

        numbers.stream()
           .reduce(result,
                  (node, val) -> {node.next= new Node(val, null); return node.next;},
                  (n1, n2) -> new Node(-1, null));

        result = result.next;
        while(result != null) {
            System.out.println(result.val);
            result = result.next;
        }
    }
}
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;

    Node(){}
    Node(int v, Node n) {
        val = v;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Hacky but neat technique. Reminds me of the good old days using C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are, as their name suggests, one-directional things. They are like production lines. You can't just go "give me the last item on the line first!" because the conveyor belts don't work that way. You *can* wait at a point on the line to collect all the items, and as you collect them, order them in the reverse order. Then put them on the production line again.

```
numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)).stream()
    .reduce(...)
```

Here I have collected it into an `ArrayDeque`, and since `ArrayDeque` is a stack structure, it reverses it. Then you can go through it with `reduce`.

Note that the "reversing the list" part doesn't need streams at all:

```
new ArrayDeque<>(number).stream().reduce(...)
// or the many other ways of reversing a list
```

In any case, you are going through the list twice. If you want to do this by going through the list once, one way I can think of is to use a mutating reduction to keep track of where the tail of the linked list is.

You need an extra helper object to keep track of the tail:

```
static class CollectHelper {
  private Node tail;
  private Node head;

  public void accumulate(int i) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = new Node(i, null);
      tail = head;
    } else {
      tail.next = new Node(i, null);
      tail = tail.next;
    }
  }

  public void combine(CollectHelper other) {
    if (other.head == null) return;
    tail.next = other.head;
    tail = other.tail;
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Node result = numbers
    .stream()
    .collect(CollectHelper::new, CollectHelper::accumulate, CollectHelper::combine).head;
```