# Alternative to stream.reduce for foreach loop in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following for each loop:

```
int someOtherVal = 0;
List<Applicators> applicatorList = List.of(applicator1, applicator2);
MyClass result = initialClassValue;

for(Applicator applicator: applicatorList) {
    result = applicator.apply(result, someOtherVal);
}
```

The closest I can get to it using Stream API is:

```
applicatorList.stream()
    .reduce(
         initialClassValue,
         (intermediateResult, applicator) -> applicator.apply(intermediateResult, someOtherVal),
         (intermediateResult1, intermediateResult2) -> intermediateResult1 // complete garbage but need to provide for parallel streams which I am not using
    )
```

Is there some other way to implement this which does not involve the needless overriding of combiner function?

My beef with using combiner function is that -

1. I am not using parallel streams, so combining of intermediate results should not be required
2. the garbage combiner override actually doesn't make sense in this context

Comment: No. I would suggest that you just stick with the for loop, or write your own `fold` helper method (that uses a for loop). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240414/equivalent-of-scalas-foldleft-in-java-8

Comment: What’s wrong with the loop? Even if you omit the combiner function, the Stream operation is not simpler (or better in any form).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by not specifying the initial value in the `reduce` method.  However, this too has its disadvantages.  Here is a related example:

- create my own sum lambda (could have used `Integer::sum`)
- it returns an `Optional<T>` of some type `T`.
- due to the lack of an initial value it returns the first via `orElse`.  But then, that is what your method would do if only one value. Or you could just return the `optional` and check if a value was present.

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> sumThem = (a,b)->a + b;
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().reduce(sumThem::apply).orElse(1);
```

But there is nothing wrong with using a loop and may be the best way to go.