# Functionally Inverting a map with a nested data structure in Java 8

Tags: java, data-structures, functional-programming

I've got a problem that's currently driving me crazy. I'm trying to avoid creation of an intermediate object for this map inversion. (Clairification on objective: I have a Map with a nested data structure that I'd like to invert and explode. So,

```
Map<Foo,Set<String>> fooStringMap
```

becomes

```
Map<String,Foo> expandedStringFooMap

//Inverting a map is simple
private <X,Y> Map<Y,X> invertMap(Map<X,Y> source){
    return source.entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getValue,Entry::getKey)

private <A,B> Map<A,B> explodeMapWithCollection(Map<? extends Collection<A>, B> collectionMap){
 collectionMap.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getKey().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),x.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue));
}
```

Currently, this is not working. I don't even think the above will compile, so just consider it pseudo code.

I've solved this using a pair like this:

```
someMap.keySet().stream().flatMap(key->someMap.get(key).stream().map(val -> new 
Pair<>(val,key))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft,Pair::getRight)));
```

That works like a charm, but I'd (for my own edification) like to avoid creating the intermediate pair. I know there's got to be a way to do it, but I seem to be lost in the synatax.

Comment: The map contains a nested data structure that I'd like to explode. Basically I have a Map<Foo,Set<String>> and I'd like to invert and explode that into a Map<String,Foo>

Comment: I think you cannot do what you want without potentially loosing data: for example, take a `Foo` instance (say `f1`) in your original Map, and assume it is associated with the strings `a, b`; another `Foo` instance (say `f2`) in the original Map is associated with the strings `a, c, d`. Now in your final `Map<String, Foo>` which `Foo` instance is associated with the String `a`?

Comment: The "Strings" in this case are all unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one approach with a custom [`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) on the entry set. One could argue that this is not "fully functional" due to the `forEach` that is hidden in the accumulator, but at some point, the map entries have to be created, and I'm not sure whether there is an "elegant" way to use the stream from the `Set`s (the entry values) and still have the possibility of access the entry key (which will become the value of the new entries).

A side note (although I'm risking downvotes by taking up the cudgels for procedural programming): You don't *have* to do it the functional way just because you can. When you say that you are "lost in the syntax", then

1. What will you think when reading this code again in a few weeks?
2. What will your coworkers think when reading this code for the first time? (I'm concerned about the one with the chainsaw and the goalie mask here...)

I'd recommend to keep it simple. (Even though the most generic procedural form still may look confusing at the first glance)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapInvert
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = 
            new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Set<String>>();

        map.put(1, new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C")));
        map.put(2, new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("D","E","F")));
        map.put(3, new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("G","H","I")));

        Map<String, Integer> resultA = inverseEx(map);
        System.out.println("Procedural: "+resultA);

        Map<String, Integer> resultB = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
            LinkedHashMap::new, 
            (m, e) -> e.getValue().forEach(v -> m.put(v, e.getKey())), 
            (m0, m1) -> m0.putAll(m1));
        System.out.println("Functional: "+resultB);
    }

    /**
     * Invert the given map, by mapping each element of the values to
     * the respective key
     *  
     * @param map The input map
     * @return The inverted map
     */
    private static <K, V> Map<V, K> inverseEx(
        Map<K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> map)
    {
        Map<V, K> result = new LinkedHashMap<V, K>();
        for (Entry<K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> e : map.entrySet())
        {
            for (V v : e.getValue())
            {
                result.put(v, e.getKey());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The collecting map is what I couldn't figure out! Thank you kind internet stranger. I'll agree that both the procedural approach and using a Pair are both much cleaner, but I knew there had to be a way using stream and collect, and you have shown me that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional version using 'reduce'. The main drawback to doing this functionally is going to result in less than stellar performance due to the lack of persistent data structures.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Test {

    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> combineMaps(Map<K,V> map1, Map<K,V> map2) {
        Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
        map.putAll(map1);
        map.putAll(map2);
        return map;
    }

    public static BiFunction<Map<String,Integer>,Map.Entry<Integer,Set<String>>,Map<String,Integer>> accumulator =
        (map, entry) -> combineMaps(map, entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> entry.getKey())));

    public static BinaryOperator<Map<String,Integer>> binOperator =
        (map1, map2) -> combineMaps(map1, map2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> setOne = new HashSet<String>();
        setOne.add("one");
        setOne.add("two");
        setOne.add("three");

        Set<String> setTwo = new HashSet<String>();
        setTwo.add("four");
        setTwo.add("five");
        setTwo.add("six");

        Map<Integer,Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>();
        myMap.put(1, setOne);
        myMap.put(2, setTwo);

        Map<String,Integer> newMap = myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .reduce(new HashMap<String,Integer>(), accumulator, binOperator);

        System.out.println(newMap.get("five"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ["cut the knot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) here, so to speak, and change the terms of the problem.  Google's excellent [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) has a [`Multimap` interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and a [`SetMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) subtype with a handful of implementations.  The documentation for `Multimap` tells us that:

> You can visualize the contents of a multimap either as a map from keys to nonempty collections of values:
>
> - a → 1, 2
> - b → 3
>
> ... or as a single "flattened" collection of key-value pairs:
>
> - a → 1
> - a → 2
> - b → 3

The `SetMultimap` type has an [`entries` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html#entries()) that returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` result.  You can straightforwardly `stream()` that and `map()` over that stream to invert the entries, and then use that stream to build an inverse map.  So something like this (which I'm sure I'm not doing the best way):

```
public static <K, V> ImmutableSetMultimap<V, K> invert(SetMultimap<? extends K, ? extends V> input) {
    return input
            .entries()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new Map.Entry<V, K>() {
                // This inner class should probably be abstracted out into its own top-level thing
                @Override
                public V getKey() {
                    return e.getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public K getValue() {
                    return e.getKey();
                }

                @Override
                public K setValue(K value) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            })
            .collect(new ImmutableSetMultimapCollector<>());
}
```

Right now Guava doesn't seem to be full up to speed with Java 8 so you'd need to write your own `ImmutableSetMultimapCollector` (or whatever output class you want to produce) but that would get reused over and over so it's worth it.  [This article gives some guidance.](http://codingjunkie.net/guava-and-java8-collectors/)

Note also that by using a `SetMultimap` as a result type we can invert, without losing information, an input where the same value is mapped to two different keys.  This may well be a plus!

So I'd highlight two lessons here:

- Guava is a really awesome library.  Learn it and use it!
- Problems often get much simpler when you use tools that are custom-designed for them.  In this case, `Multimap` is such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for simplicity you want to transform a `Map<Long, Set<String>>` where `String` values are *unique* across keys, into a `Map<String, Long>`.

I think this operation is a *fold left* with an accumulator of type `Map<String, Long>`, which in Java 8 becomes a reduction with an *accumulator* and a *combiner*: see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), and also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316429/162684).

One way of writing it is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Long, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, new HashSet<String>());
    map.get(1L).add("a");
    map.get(1L).add("b");
    map.put(2L, new HashSet<>());
    map.get(2L).add("c");
    map.get(2L).add("d");
    map.get(2L).add("e");
    Map<String, Long> result = map.entrySet().stream().reduce(
            new HashMap<String, Long>(), 
            (accumulator, entry) -> {
                // building an accumulator of type Map<String, Long> from a Map.Entry<Long, Set<String>>
                entry.getValue().forEach(s -> accumulator.put(s, entry.getKey()));
                return accumulator;
            }, 
            (accumulator1, accumulator2) -> {
                // merging two accumulators of type Map<String, Long>
                accumulator1.keySet().forEach(k -> accumulator2.put(k, accumulator1.get(k)));
                return accumulator2;
            }
        );
    result.keySet().forEach(k -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + result.get(k)));
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
a -> 1
b -> 1
c -> 2
d -> 2
e -> 2
```

---

Note: this is the same idea as in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799189/162684), which I didn't notice before :)