# Terminal operation to evaluate intermediate operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let says i have a list of strings and i want to use those strings as input to a fluent builder.

```
List<String> scripts;

//initialize list

ScriptRunnerBuilder scriptRunnerBuilder = new ScriptRunnerBuilder();

BiFunction<String,ScriptRunnerBuilder,ScriptRunnerBuilder> addScript = 
(script,builder) -> builer.addScript(script);

scriptRunnerBuilder = scripts.stream.map(script -> 
addScript.apply(script,scriptRunnerBuilder)).......

scriptRunnerBuilder.build();
```

which terminal operation can i use so that the addScript function gets called for all elements in the list?

The issue is that the ScriptRunnerBuilder is immutable whereby ScriptRunnerBuilder.addScript() returns a new ScriptRunnerBuilder object rather than modifying existing – so i can't just us a foreach.

My intentions are to carry the result of the addScript() call and use that as input for the next element in the stream

Comment: scripts.forEach(script -> 
addScript.apply(script,scriptRunnerBuilder));

Comment: Yes, but does it has to return? You have a reference to the builder. It does not have to return anything.

Comment: I know i could use reduce operation but that is unnecessary as we are not combining results

Answer (score 5):

In simplest way this should:

```
// create your builder
ScriptRunnerBuilder builder = new ScriptRunnerBuilder();

// add all scripts
scripts.forEach(script-> builder.addScript(script))

build results
scriptRunnerBuilder.build();
```

Because builder aggregates all data, and you have created it outside forEach lambda, you can access it directly. This will lead to less code and same result.

Or as @Holger suggested:

```
scripts.forEach(builder::addScript);
```

Comment: Or even `scripts.forEach(builder::addScript);`

Comment: The issue is that the ScriptRunnerBuilder is immutable whereby ScriptRunnerBuilder.addScript() returns a new ScriptRunnerBuilder object rather than modifying existing

Comment: @Claudiga then use an ordinary loop, `for(String s: scripts) builder = builder.addScript(s);`

Comment: @Holger yea that sounds like the only clean way to do it. I just wanted to see how it could be done using streams

Answer (score 2):

Use `forEach` instead of `map` and don't assign the result of the stream anymore

```
scripts.forEach(script -> addScript.apply(script,scriptRunnerBuilder));
```

Answer (score 1):

> i could use reduce operation but that is unnecessary as we are not combining results

Combining is exactly what you are doing.
You combine all scripts from `List<String>` to `ScriptRunnerBuilder` aren't you?

I agree that the @Beri's solution without stream probably is the simplest. But also there is a way with [`reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method where you don't need to create `ScriptRunnerBuilder` before:

```
ScriptRunnerBuilder builder = scripts.stream()
        .reduce(new ScriptRunnerBuilder(), ScriptRunnerBuilder::addScript, (b1, b2) -> b1);
```

See more: [Why is a combiner needed for reduce method that converts type in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308146/why-is-a-combiner-needed-for-reduce-method-that-converts-type-in-java-8)

**Update** To not to rely on the fact that `combiner` not being invoked for sequential stream and to make it works with parallel one you have to implement the real `combiner`.

If you could add an overrided method `addScript(ScriptRunnerBuilder otherBuilder)` then the `reduce` will look like:

```
.reduce(new ScriptRunnerBuilder(), ScriptRunnerBuilder::addScript, 
        ScriptRunnerBuilder::addScript)
```