# Rewrite Imperative For Loop With Declarative Approach using Java Stream API

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have list of http query params in `NamveValuePair` format and a `WebTarget` ([javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html)). Then I am simply attaching those query params to `WebTarget` one by one using imperative approach.

I know that it's easy to apply stream when all the elements are in the data type. But I failed to apply the same solution when they are not.

**This is the code I wan to rewrite using Java Streams API**

```java
 public WebTarget attachQueryParams(List<NameValuePair> queryParams, WebTarget webTarget) {

    for (NameValuePair param : queryParams) {
      webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(param.getName(), param.getValue());
    }
    return webTarget;
  }
```

I tried to rewrite it using stream `reduce` function as follows with no luck so far:

```
queryParams.stream().reduce(webTarget,((webTarget1, pair) -> webTarget1.queryParam(pair.getName(),pair.getValue())))
```

Comment: What is the problem, the error ?

Comment: `webTarget1`s data type is `NameValuePair`  instead of `WebTarget`. Therefore applying `queryParam` is not possible.

Comment: What's wrong with the for loop? Why do you want to rewrite it?

Comment: I prefer more `pure function` approach, and this for loop is modifying webTarget on each loop.

Comment: Keep your for loop that is much more readable and elegant.

Comment: I honestly love the functional approach most of the times but in Java it seems a bit...off. Sometimes it seems it's making me jump through hoops for something that should be trivial. Not *all* stream operations are like that, mind you, but `reduce` certainly is. The process of "reduce a bunch of type `A`s reduce them to type `B`" is pretty much idiomatic. Yet in Java, you either need to use the three parameter method (which I always have to lookup how exactly it expects to work) or do something like cascading Collectors to get the same result. I find it ugly. I'd also suggest keeping the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```java
queryParams.stream()
        .reduce(webTarget,
                (webTarget1, pair) -> webTarget1.queryParam(pair.getName(),pair.getValue()),
                (v1, v2) -> v1);
```

Why you need third parameter you can find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24308146/11733759)