# CASE WHEN in querydsl generate from list

Tags: querydsl

I would like to create a `NumberExpression` for the `SELECT` clause in QueryDsl using a `CASE WHEN THEN` construct for retrieving session number (business data).
Currently, I'm having this kind of method that create SQL in `String` which is bad for many reasons.

```java
    private static StringBuilder getSelectStatement(
        UUID jobInstanceUuid,
        LocalDateTime jobInstanceStartDateTime,
        List<CotCandidate> cotCandidates
    ) {
        StringBuilder selectStatement = new StringBuilder();
        selectStatement.append("SELECT ");
        selectStatement.append(getCaseOfSessionNumber(cotCandidates));
        // skipped other fields for clarity
        selectStatement.append(getFromStatement());
       // skipped where, having, groupBy statements for clarity
       selectStatement.append(" ");

        return selectStatement;
    }

    private static String getCaseOfSessionNumber(List<CotCandidate> cotCandidates) {
        StringBuilder caseSessionNumber = new StringBuilder();
        caseSessionNumber.append("CASE ");
        cotCandidates.forEach(cot -> {
            caseSessionNumber.append(" WHEN (P.SETTLEMENT_SYSTEM = ");
            caseSessionNumber.append(toSqlString(cot.getSettlementSystem()));
            caseSessionNumber.append(" AND P.PAYMENT_MODE = ");
            caseSessionNumber.append(toSqlString(cot.getPaymentMode()));
            caseSessionNumber.append(" ) THEN ");
            caseSessionNumber.append(cot.getSessionNumb());
            caseSessionNumber.append(" ");
        });
        caseSessionNumber.append("END");
        return caseSessionNumber.toString();
    }
```

And with querydsl I would like to achived smth like that:

```java
    void getJobExecutionQuery(List<CotCandidate> cotCandidates) {
        QPaymentOrderEntity order = QPaymentOrderEntity.paymentOrderEntity;
        JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
        List<Tuple> tuple = queryFactory
            .from(order)
            .select(
                getSessionNumb(cotCandidates, order),
            )
            .fetch();
    }

    // This doesn't work cause without otherwise() in the end it return Case.Builder.Cases
    private NumberExpression<Integer> getSessionNumb(List<CotCandidate> cotCandidates, QPaymentOrderEntity order) {
        return cotCandidates.stream()
            .map( cot ->
            Expressions.cases()
                    .when(order.settlementSystem.eq(cot.getSettlementSystem())
                        .and(order.paymentMode.eq(cot.getPaymentMode())))
                    .then(cot.getSessionNumb())
            ).collect(?);
    }

The problem is that I don't know how to build dynamicly case when then : 
To be like that: 

            NumberExpression<Integer> sessionNumber = new CaseBuilder()
            .when(
                order.settlementSystem.eq(cotCandidates.get(0).getSettlementSystem())
                .and(order.paymentMode.eq(cotCandidates.get(0).getPaymentMode())))
            .then(cotCandidates.get(0).getSessionNumb())
            .when(
                order.settlementSystem.eq(cotCandidates.get(n).getSettlementSystem())
                    .and(order.paymentMode.eq(cotCandidates.get(n).getPaymentMode())))
            .then(cotCandidates.get(n).getSessionNumb())
            .otherwise(-1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a CASE statement consists of three parts:

1. Initial case (`CaseBuilder`)
2. The middle part (`CaseBuilder.Cases`)
3. The final part (`CaseBuilder.Cases#otherwise(...)`)

Unfortunately these builder types provide no common interface which basically throws your options for a fluent reducer out of the window. The initial case always has to be dealt with inidivually:

```java
QPaymentOrderEntity order = QPaymentOrderEntity.paymentOrderEntity;
CaseBuilder caseBuilder = Expressions.cases();
CotCandidate candidate = candidates.get(0);
CaseBuilder.Cases<Integer, NumberExpression<Integer>> intermediateBuilder = caseBuilder.when(order.paymentMode.eq(candidate.getPaymentMode())
        .and(order.settlementSystem.eq(candidate.getSettlementSystem()))).then(candidate.getSessionNumb());

for (int i = 1; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
    candidate = candidates.get(i); 
    intermediateBuilder = intermediateBuilder.when(order.paymentMode.eq(candidate.getPaymentMode())).then(candidate.getSessionNumb());
}

NumberExpression<Integer> finalExpression = intermediateBuilder.otherwise(-1);
```

The loop is technically a `foldLeft` operation. Unfortunately that can't be expressed in a `Stream` easily, as the Stream API only provides the parallelizable `reduce` operation. Two different `CaseWhen` builders can't be combined, and therefore this operation is not parallelizable. For a more detailed answer on `foldLeft` versus `reduce`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316429/2104280 .

---

On a side note:

Aren't you reinventing the wheel here? From the properties on `QPaymentOrderEntity` it seems that `PaymentMode` and `SettlementSystem` are managed types. The query would probably be a lot easier to just join the `CotCandidates` and get the `sessionNumb` from there;

```java
query().from(order).innerJoin(QCotCandidate.cotCandidate)
   .on(QCotCandidate.cotCandidate.settlementSystem.eq(order.settlementSystem)
       .and(QCotCandidate.paymentMode.settlementSystem.eq(order.paymentMode))
   .select(order, QCotCandidate.cotCandidate.sessionNumb)
```

Anyways, it `CotCandiate` might not be a managed entity. In which case you'll need a `VALUES` clause, which JPQL by default hasn't. (You might want to consider the [`blaze-persistence-querydsl`](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#managed-type-value-clause) integration for that).

Comment: Thanks for clarification about CASE WHEN in querydsl - turns out it was my missing knowledge about this lib. 

CotCandidate is not a entity unfortunately, so I can't make simple join on it.
I will try with blaze if we have it in our org repository, in other case I will try to managed with Criteria API from JPA. 

Anyway thanks for fast reply!